# Make a pop up before placing cookies

Tags: php, web-crawler

Because of the new EU cookie law, i need to implement a cookie solution on my site. I wan't to make a simple pop-up, wich tells the user we use cookies, and a button they can click "agree" on. My problem is just, that my site is setting cookies all over the site, so i need to make to popup box, somehow, before placing the cookies. Is there any way you can make a pop-up, and then first when it's closed, it will execute the rest of the PHP code?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it might be. But any solution that works will be acceptet.

Comment: What's funny with this law is that almost no website respect it, even major ones...

Comment: Yeah, true. It's really fail. But i just wan't to sure i don't get into trouble.

Comment: It's questionable whether that EU guideline actually is converted into your countrys law. If not, you can probably ignore it. If yes, stick to your local law. Note that this EU guideline is NOT new anymore, it's reference number `2009/136/EG` suggests it started in 2009, and local law should have been implemented until May 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all my projects I allow cookies by default on the first page, I display the pop-up and if the user reject I delete cookies and do not use any cookie anymore.

It depends on your website, but I think you don't need to block a part of your website until the user accept cookies and use a "standard" way.

Also what you want to achieve is not very good for SEO. 
If you redirect your user to another page crawlers won't be able to check your website, and if all pages redirect to the same page you will have a very bad ranking.

**Update:**

It is not required to block all cookies as mentionned in the [EU cookie law (e-Privacy Directive)](http://www.ico.org.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies) since June 2012:

> European data protection authorities opinion In June 2012, European
>   data protection authorities (as part of the Article 29 Working Party)
>   adopted an opinion which clarifies that some cookie uses might be
>   exempt from the requirement to gain consent:
>
> Some cookies can be exempted from informed consent under certain
>   conditions if they are not used for additional purposes. These cookies
>   include cookies used to keep track of a user’s input when filling
>   online forms or as a shopping cart, also known as session-id cookies,
>   multimedia player session cookies and user interface customisation
>   cookies, eg language preference cookies to remember the language
>   selected by the user. First party analytics cookies are not likely to
>   create a privacy risk if websites provide clear information about the
>   cookies to users and privacy safeguards, eg a user friendly mechanism
>   to opt out from any data collection and where they ensure that
>   identifiable information is anonymised.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the best for SEO, but the solution i'm using now is even worse. I redirect users to totally different page, as the first thing...

Comment: I don't absolutely want to find a workaround to what you want, but I think you should not implement this in that way. The first time I access to a website I will leave it asap if I am redirected to a "Privacy policy"-like page. You should use my logic or use another alternative. Also if you redirect your user to another page crawlers won't be able to check your website, and if all pages redirect to the same page you will have a very bad ranking.

Comment: Yes, i know - that's my problem. But in my country (Denmark) we need to get the users permission BEFORE were placing any kind of cookie. And that's a problem, as my website is made with an engine not programmed by me, so i don't even know what the cookies are used to...

Comment: Is there a specific rule in Denmark? because it is part of the EU and then this law ;) I edited my answer, in summary you don't need the user agreement for some cookies. It depends if your website/engine, but in your case it should be fine to accept by default all cookies except tracking ones (e.g. ads, Analytics, ...)

Comment: Many countries look different on the law, and there are specific rules for us in Denmark.